# FileNotFoundException sequence files Mahout

Tags: hadoop, mahout, sequencefile

I'm reading *Apache Mahout Cookbook*. But I have a problem in chapter 2, creating a sequence file.
I'm using Mahout 0.9

The command I'm executing is as follows:

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout seqdirectory -i /home/haritz/Escritorio/work_dir/original -o /home/haritz/Escritorio/work_dir/sequencefiles
```

But I obtain the following error:

```
Running on hadoop, using /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: /home/haritz/mahout-distribution-0.9/mahout-examples-0.9-job.jar
15/03/16 16:45:57 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--charset=[UTF-8], --chunkSize=[64], --endPhase=[2147483647], --fileFilterClass=[org.apache.mahout.text.PrefixAdditionFilter], --input=[/home/haritz/Escritorio/work_dir/original], --keyPrefix=[], --method=[mapreduce], --output=[/home/haritz/Escritorio/work_dir/sequencefiles], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp]}
15/03/16 16:45:58 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/03/16 16:45:58 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
15/03/16 16:45:58 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.compress.map.output is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.compress
15/03/16 16:45:58 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /home/haritz/Escritorio/work_dir/original
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.runMapReduce(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java:162)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.run(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.main(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Can anybody tell me why I obtain this exception?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
It is expecting hdfs path for input and output. give the hdfs paths.

mahout seqdirectory -i Hdfs-Path(hdfs://ip/user/--) -o Hdfs-path(hdfs://ip/user/..)

If you want run it on locally ,that is input from local file system and output  to local file system,you need to set property in /bin/mahout shell file

  MAHOUT_LOCAL=true
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I also want to add something just in case somebody has the same problem. After donig what you told me, I this problem: Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
The solution is quite simple: export MAHOUT_HEAPSIZE=512 I'm in a virtual machine so I didn't have enough memory, by default it takes 1000MB.